# Equally distributed/packed spheres within a sphere

Tags: algorithms, packing

I need to equally distribute a variable number of spheres within a larger sphere (the volume of the spheres depends on how many there are).  Are there any algorithms for doing this? An approximate solution would be acceptable.

When searching, I was only able to find material about equally distributing points on the surface of a sphere, whereas I want to distribute the points within the volume of the sphere.

Comment: How approximate is good enough?  An obvious solution would be to just pack 3D space with the small spheres and then delete any sphere that is not completely inside the larger one.

Comment: Sorry for my english and thanks for the edit. I have have an exact number of small spheres, but from case to case this number varies. If i understand right your idea would take the size of a sphere as initial point.

But yes, it can be "very" approximate.